# Java get one JSONObject from a JsonArray and set json response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I  have a Json array

```
{
   "id":33,
   "dataContent":"user1",
   "temp":"36"
},
{
   "id":33,
   "dataContent":"user2",
   "temp":"36"
},
{
   "id":33,
   "dataContent":"user3",
   "temp":"39"
},
{
   "id":21,
   "dataContent":"user4",
   "temp":"38"
},
{
   "id":22,
   "dataContent":"user5",
   "temp":"37"
}
```

that am generating using the code

```
@PostMapping(value = "/temperature")
    public ResponseEntity<?> Temperature(@Valid @RequestBody Activation activation) {
        Temperature temperature = new Temperature();
        temperature.setCode(activation.getDataContent());
        temperature.setDatecreated(new Date());
        temperature.setUser_id(activation.getId());
        temperature.setTemperature(activation.getTemp());
        temperatureRepository.save(temperature);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Temperature Updated");
    }
```

how can I set a check in such a way that the if the temperature is greater than 38 set a json response as not cleared and if it is less than 38 the response returned is cleared.

```
{

   "message":"cleared"

}
```

Comment: That's not a JSON array, because arrays start with `[`

Comment: That code is not *generating* any JSON, and it is certainly not doing any array/list handling.

Comment: What would you like the JSON response to look like? Show an example (in the question, not in a comment).

Comment: Hi @Andreas have added how JSON response to look like

Comment: To set a check, write an `if` statement, then return "cleared" or "not cleared". Which part of that seems difficult? Perhaps the part where a list of temperatures might require multiple difference responses all at the same time?

Comment: If you want returned JSON to be `{"message":"some text"}`, then create a class with a field named `message` of type `String`, then pass an instance of that class to the `ok()` method. Make sure to enhance the `@PostMapping` to specify that the response is JSON. Did you do *any* research on this? There are lot of examples for this on the web.

Comment: can you show me an example please @Andreas

Comment: An example of what? A class with a single field? Creating an instance of the class? An `if` statement to set the desired message text? Giving the instance on the `ok()` call? Which of these very simple operations needs an example to be understood? --- But ok: `return ResponseEntity.ok(new Message(temperature.getTemperature() < 38 ? "Cleared" : "Not cleared"));` and I'm assuming you know how to create the class `Message` with a single `String` field named `message`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class with field named message.

   ```
    public class Message {

        private String message;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }


    }
   ```
2. Then, in your above method,

   ```
    Message m = new Message();

    if(activation.getTemp() > 38) {
        m.setMessage("not cleared);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(m);

    }
    else{
        m.setMessage("cleared");
        return ResponseEntity.status.ok().body(m);
    }
   ```

Comment: Why `ok().body(m)` instead of just `ok(m)`?

Comment: `ResponseEntity.status.ok()`?

Comment: They both serve the same purpose. You can do it either way.